# Reading file names from database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, filenames

I am trying to get the names of the files for my list, problem is that I get them with the path, like, "storage/emulated/0/recording-01-08-2017 04-19-23 PM.3gp".
So I used .replaceAll("[^\d-]", " "); and still I get that "0" at the beginning and it looks like, "0 01-08-2017 04-19-23 3"

What can I do if I want to get just the name of the file (dateTime) ?

//getting the date for naming the files

```
    String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss aa", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    outPutFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording -" + dateTime + ".3gp";

    final String DIR_DATABASE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording";
    String sqliteQuery= "CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS Recordings (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , fileName VARCHAR)";
    SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DIR_DATABASE + "db.sqlite", null);
    database.execSQL(sqliteQuery);
```

//getting the file names

```
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT fileName FROM Recordings", null);
    ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String fileName = cursor.getString(0).replaceAll("[^\\d-]", " ");
        fileNames.add(fileName);
    }
    cursor.close();
    database.close();
```

//list and list view

```
    listRecord.addAll(fileNames);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listRecord);
    recordList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: Why don't you just look for the last index of "/" and then substring from that index to the end ? or Use Uri to parse it in segment and then get last segment. And if you want only date and time then substring from first "-" until last dot (".").

Comment: Have you tried to use `new File("/storage/emulated/0/recording-01-08-2017 04-19-23 PM.3gp").getName()`

Comment: There's a lot of files, not one... I need to do that for every new recording (I am building voice recorder app)